# Jenkins Text Finder doesn't find my regex

Tags: regex, jenkins

I've added Text Finder to Jenkins to set my build "unstable" if the word Timeout or Time out is find in console output...

It works with other regex but not on these words...

My regex is :

```
.*Time\s*[oO]ut.*
```

I tested it on regexplanet with my error :

Deployment Time Out. Received exception Timeout::Error : execution expired

But if I set this "regex" :

```
Deployment Time Out
```

It works. Is there any tip ?

Comment: try `.*Time *[oO]ut.*` because some tools won't support `\s`

Comment: Same result with this...

Comment: With this one Timeout will not working, I already tried .*Timeout.*

Comment: It worked for me with that plugin and your exact regex....

Comment: I just find this : https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?mode=hide&reset=true&jqlQuery=project+%3D+JENKINS+AND+status+in+%28Open%2C+%22In+Progress%22%2C+Reopened%29+AND+component+%3D+%27text-finder-plugin%27

My script pass the buildstate to fail before Text Finder find the regex, it's an issue. I'll try to change it